# ASP.Net MVC, JS injection and System.ArgumentException - Illegal Characters in path

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.Net MVC application, I use **custom error handling**.
I want to perform custom actions for each error case I meet in my application.

So I override **Application_Error**, get the  **Server.GetLastError();**
and do my business depending on the exception, the current user, the current URL (the application runs on many domains), the user IP, and many others.

Obviousely, the application is often the target of hackers.
In almost all the case it's not a problem to detect and manage it, but for some **JS URL attacks**, my error handling does not perform what I want it to do.
Ex (from logs) :

```
http://localhost:1809/Scripts/]||!o.support.htmlSerialize&&[1
```

When I got such an URL, an exception is raised when accessing the **ConnectionStrings** section in the **web.config**, and I can't even redirect to another URL.

It leads to a "***System.ArgumentException - Illegal Characters in path***, etc."

The screenshot below shows the problem :
http://screencast.com/t/Y2I1YWU4

An obvious solution is to write a **HTTP module** to filter the urls before they reach my application, but I'd like to avoid it because :

- I like having the whole security being managed in one place (in the **Application_Error()** method)
- In the module I cannot access the whole data I have in the application itself (application specific data I don't want to debate here)

**Questions :**
Did you meet this problem ?
How did you manage it ?

Thanks for you suggestions,

Mose

*PS : here is the stack trace :*

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPhysicalPathForPath(String path, VirtualDirectoryMapping mapping)
at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String siteID, VirtualPath path, String& directory, String& baseName)
at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.MapPath(String siteID, String path)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp)
at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
at System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData()
at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpContext.get_ImpersonationToken()
at System.Web.ClientImpersonationContext.Start(HttpContext context, Boolean throwOnError)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ThreadContext.Enter(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace / inner exception details?